# Azure Virtual machine scale set and .NET Core application

Tags: azure, load-balancing, virtual-machines, .net

I am experimenting with Azure Virtual machine scale sets in order to achieve load balancing of the .NET Core application.

Configuring actual scale set seems straightforward.

Now, it comes with the second part - publishing actual .NET application to that scale set. Maybe it's obvious but cannot find any documentation.

The question is, how to publish the .NET core application to the Virtual machine scale set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get your application onto each of the scale set VMs and configure it. There are really two routes to doing this:

1. Build a custom image that has your application on it already configured and use this image for your scale set
2. Use the default image and apply your application and configuration at run time

Option 1 is more complicated as you need to build an image, but if your application is large and startup time of the VMs is important then you may need to do this. You can look at tools like [Packer](https://packer.io/) to automate the creation of images.

Option 2 is simpler, but you will need to find the right tool to do the configuration for you. The easiest options are either using the [custom script extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows), or the [DSC extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-dsc). You can also use configuration management tools like Chef, Puppet, Ansible etc.

There is also the third option to manually logon to each VM and install it but you really don't want to do that, as you will loose your changes whenever you scale up or down.